# How to wait unitl xhr finished?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a website where I need to get all people who are registered to an event but every time I make the xhr request the code execute and do not wait the xrh response, that's cause a lot of trouble in the following code...

```
let inscrit = new XMLHttpRequest();
let methode = "GET";
let url = "php/getInscrit.php";
let asynchronous = true;

inscrit.open(methode, url, asynchronous);
inscrit.timeout = 4000;
inscrit.onload = function () {
  let people;

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    people = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  }
};
inscrit.send(null);
return people;
```

Sorry for my bad English and ty

Comment: how do u know its not executing on time? did u try console logging it?

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem I made an console log when I call this function and "people" is alwais null and In my network console it prove me that's not null

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is in "onload", which is only called one time, which could be right at the beginning before it's fully loaded, instead you should do everything in the `onreadystatechange` callback, so for example:

```
  let inscrit = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let methode = "GET";
    let url = "php/getInscrit.php"
    let asynchronous = true;

    inscrit.open(methode, url, asynchronous);
    inscrit.timeout = 4000;
    inscrit.onreadystatechange = function() {


        let people ;

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            people = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


        }
    }
    inscrit.send(null);
    return people ;
```

Comment: "which could be right at the beginning before it's fully loaded" — No. The entire point of the load event is that it fires just **after** it is fully loaded.

Comment: This code won't work either (for the same reason that the original code doesn't: It returns before the value is assigned to `people` in the callback).

Comment: @Quentin OP never said this was inside of a function, so "return" could be superfluous

Comment: If it isn't inside a function then the question doesn't make any sense at all. We can safely infer that it is.

Comment: @Quentin y doesnt it make sense? this can all be happening on page load